# Displaying NSArray with content from JSON in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

Hi i am trying to display content from an NSArray in a table view but having problems with `NSString *place= [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` i am trying to increment the objectAtIndex so the results from the json are display. The following is the error i am getting:

```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
> objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x714bda0'
```

I have also tried the following but i am getting error with that also:

> NSDictionary *place= [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
 #import "leagueTableViewController.h"

  #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

   #define kjsonURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.statsfc.com/premier-        league/table.json?key=o"]
   @interface leagueTableViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation leagueTableViewController{

  NSMutableArray *jsonResults;
   }

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
  {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:

                    kjsonURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)

                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

});
}




- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

NSError* error;

NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

jsonResults= [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *team = [jsonResults valueForKey:@"team"];

NSString *position = [jsonResults valueForKey:@"position"];

NSLog(@"team: %@", team); //3

 NSLog(@"position: %@", position);

[self.tableView reloadData];



 }


 -(IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender {

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


 }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
 {
return [jsonResults count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


NSString *place= [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *position1 = [place valueForKey:@"position"];
NSString *won= [place valueForKey:@"won"];
NSString *lost= [place valueForKey:@"lost"];
NSString *played= [place valueForKey:@"played"];
NSString *points= [place valueForKey:@"points"];

cell.textLabel.text = [place valueForKey:@"team"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Position: %@ Played: %@ won:  %@ lost: %@ Points: %@",position1,played,won,lost,points];



return cell;


  }


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either misinterpreting the structure of the JSON returned, or you don't do what you are actually trying to do, or both. It seems to me you want to display **all** the teams, so

```
jsonResults = [json objectAtIndex:0];
```

is wrong, `jsonResults` should be directly the return value of the `NSJSONSerialization` method:

```
jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

(Add a `retain` if you're not using ARC, since this method returns an autoreleased object.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that `jsonResults` is not a `NSArray` but a `NSDictionary`.

**Edit:** As @H2CO3 correctly said, `json` already is the `NSArray` you want to use. Use `[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get a `NSDictionary` with all the details you want to display in the according `tableViewCell`.

Comment: Fairly new to ios any direction in what i need to change would be helpful